# How do I shift an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

so I am trying to do a couple of things. First **I want to shift the array based on the user input**. So let's say the user enters (in this order): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I want to shift it so that it becomes 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.

As you can see, this particular array is scalable, i.e the dimensions aren't fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrayShift(int *a, int intLength);


int main() {

int arr[10] = {0};  //array for input numbers
int array = 0;

printf("Enter the size of the array (MAX): ");
scanf("%d", &array);
printf("Now please enter your %d values: \n", array);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < array; i++) {
    scanf("%d", arr+i);
}

return 0;
}
```

Then I want to print out the and **then create a function that multiplies each number by the one before it (after shifting it**): so using the same numbers as before (2, 3, 4, 5, 1), we should get an output of 2, 6, 12, 20, 5.

Comment: Yes, you can: just multiply each element (except the first one) by the previous element.

Comment: That's a rotation, not a shift. A shift (that doesn't rotate elements to the other end of the array) could be done with `memmove`. Do you want to rotate an arbitrary number of positions, or just by one?

Comment: @KeithThompsonI just want to rotate the numbers by 1

Comment: Show what you have tried. Hint: a piece of paper and a pencil may help here.

Comment: BTW: the array dimension here _is_ fixed: `int arr[10]`;.

Comment: And you should name your variables correctly: `array` should rather be `nbelements`. When you read `array` you don't think immediately that it might be the number of elements, you'd rather think it's the array itself, but if you see `nbelements`, you immediately know what it is.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, it's fixed in that sense but it's still scalable up to that point. That's besides the point though

Answer (score 1):

It seems this could be done simply.  For the described 'rotation' we can just copy the first element to after the last, change the starting index and call it rotated without moving all the data.  And other simplifications:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number_elements;

    printf("Enter the size of the array (MAX): ");
    (void) scanf("%d", &number_elements); // should test return value in case of bad input

    int array[number_elements + 1]; // array for input numbers (over allocate by 1 for rotation)

    printf("Now please enter your %d values:\n", number_elements);
    for (int i = 0; i < number_elements; i++)
    {
        (void) scanf("%d", array + i); // ditto re return value
    }

    array[number_elements] = array[0]; // rotated array now starts at 1

    for (int i = 1; i <= number_elements; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]); // print the rotated array
        array[i - 1] *= array[i]; // multiply the rotated array
    }

    putchar('\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < number_elements; i++) // multiplied array starts at 0 again
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]); // printing the multiplied, rotated array
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
% ./a.out
Enter the size of the array (MAX): 5
Now please enter your 5 values:
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1 
2 6 12 20 5 
%
```

I'm not sure your text and your example agree with one another so this is my assumption of what you want but it can be tweaked as needed.

Comment: Yeah this works. I'll show you the code that I have and tell you the problems that I am having. I can't post it here so I'll post it as an "answer"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

```
#include <stdio.h>
void arrayRotate(int a[], int intLength)
{
int temp = a[0],t,i; // storing the first element in a temporary variable
for(i=1;i<intLength;i++)
   a[i-1] = a[i]; // Left shifting the elements starting from index 1
a[i-1] = temp; // In the last the first index element is restored back
}
void multArr(int a[],int b[],int n)
{
int i;
b[0] = a[0]; // copying the value at index 0 to the new array
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{ 
    b[i] = a[i]*a[i-1]; // performing the multiplication on the new array
}                       // referencing the values from the old array
}
int main() {
int arr[10] = {0}, cpy[10];  //array for input numbers
int array = 0;
printf("Enter the size of the array (MAX): ");
scanf("%d", &array);
printf("Now please enter your %d values: \n", array);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < array; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", arr+i);
}
arrayRotate(arr,array); // calling function for rotating
multArr(arr,cpy,array); // calling function for the multiplication stuff
for (i = 0; i < array; i++) // printing the rotated array
{
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}   
printf("\n");
for (i = 0; i < array; i++) // printing the multiplied array
{
    printf("%d ", cpy[i]);
}  
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make of it but an explanation of why you did certain things would've been nice 

Comment: Yup.. Editing..

Comment: Do you still have doubts?

Comment: I'll go through it now that I have more tangible things to look at. Thanks for taking the time to explain it

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to do.. Copying parts from cdlane, copying parts from me.. Realize one thing.. What I'm doing is rotating the array. What cdlane is, just re-indexing the array.. Just two approaches for the same thing. Then I and cdlane are both using another loop for the multiplication.. And what you are doing is implementing cdlane 's multiplication in my rotation logic..

Either use any approach to rotate, then multiply it and modify the same array, using 2 loops or first by re-indexing and then using a loop..

Comment: and whose answer you think suits best, please mark it as a solution because this question is still marked as unsolved..

Answer (score 0):

Alright so here's what I've got so far. It's kind of working but it's also not. Specifically, the problem is when I run it, it prints 6, 12, 20, 5 1, and not 2, 6, 12, 20, 5 (this is assuming the numbers of the array are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

```
#include <stdio.h>


void shift (int arr[], int num);
void multiply (int arr[], int num);

int main() {

int arr[10] = {0};  //array for input numbers
int array = 0;

printf("Enter the size of the array (MAX): ");
scanf("%d", &array);
printf("Now please enter your %d values: \n", array);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < array; i++) {
    scanf("%d", arr+i);
}

shift(arr, array);


return 0;
}


//shift function
void shift (int arr[], int num) {
int tempVar; //temporary variable
int i;

tempVar = arr[0]; //setting the temporary variable to the first element of a
for (i = 0; i < num -1; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i +1];
    printf("    %d     ", arr[i]);
    arr[i -1] *= arr[i];
}                                   //arr[0] = tempVar * arr[0];
arr[i] = tempVar;                   //i < num, print(arr[i])
printf("%d \n", arr[i]);

for ( int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    printf("    %d   ", arr[i]);
}
printf("\n");

}
```